# php / templating vs echoing

Tags: php, performance, template-engine

i would like to know which one is the best for performance:

1- use smarty template ( or any other better)

```
<?php
$Smarty = new Smarty();
// set all the default variables and other config
$Smarty->assign('var1', 'hello');
$Smarty->assign('var2', 'world');
$Smarty->display('page.html');
```

2- use this code:

```
<?php
$var1 = 'hello';
$var2 = 'world';
echo "$var1 $var2";
```

3- use this code:

```
<?php
$var1 = 'hello';
$var2 = 'world';
echo $var1 . " " . $var2;
```

based on these 3 examples i cant think about a new one, which one is best to use when performance

note: of course i have more variables than this example.

thanks

Comment: If you go back two years on SO, answers to these types of questions were always, "don't optimize prematurely!" and, "if you're that worried about performance, don't use PHP." That seems to have gone out of fashion, but it's still true. Obviously, since PHP is interpreted (normally), less code = better performance, so a template engine will be slower.

Comment: As far as PHP being bad for performance that's only if you code poorly, as far as don't optimize prematurely -- I learned that the hard way. Seriously, take that to heart. Find the bottleneck and fix that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I remember, concatenating PHP variables (as in your third example) is faster than using `"$var1 $var2"` given a mix of variables and constant strings as each token is evaluated on the fly (which is bad).

So, between 2 and 3, I believe it depends on context: If you have a long string with a mix of variables and constants, then method 3 would be faster. Otherwise, if it's identical to your example, 2 might be faster (*however, the difference is negligible and therefore should be a moot point*).

Using a templating engine will always be slower than raw code.

---

**Now** if you don't have a **very good reason** to not use a templating engine, you should by all accounts use one. Why?

- **Separation of concerns**: Your PHP shouldn't care about your HTML and vice versa.
- **Maintenance**: Maintaining can become a nightmare when you mix HTML and PHP (or any other language for that matter) and should really be avoided at all cost (unless you're doing something blindingly trivial).

Comment: I disagree with the template engine -- even if you're throwing frameworks into that term. I don't think Frameworks, in concept, are bad, but I built my own because the others didn't satisfy my speed needs. While their objective is to simplify they can often times complicate matters.

Comment: @Kerry: Two things - 1) If you want to spend a ridiculous amount of time (relatively) rolling your own and dealing with bugs/exploits that frameworks will have (usually) already fixed, that's great. 2) If speed is of great concern, then you shouldn't be using PHP :)

Comment: @Kerry: Also, for the most part, frameworks only complicate things if you don't understand them and/or how they work. They can also be tweaked for speed when needed. I would really find any developer who *didn't* use a framework as being suspect in any interview.

Comment: @ Demian -- I don't mean to start a fight or be directly insulting. Rasmus Lerdorf: http://www.sitepoint.com/rasmus-lerdorf-php-frameworks-think-again/ -- but even CI slows things down drastically. As he says, you should take what you need, that's it, so I made what I need, based off other frameworks (not from the ground up). The systems I build are constantly praised for their speed (among other things). Also, for sites using PHP: Facebook, Yahoo, eBay, Digg, etc., PHP is fine for speed.

Comment: @Kerry: Don't worry, I didn't take your post as being insulting at all :).. Your clarification (taking what you need) definitely makes sense and I wouldn't be opposed to that at all :). In 90% of cases, if built properly you're right - PHP is fine for speed (let's not get into discussions about relative productivity though ;)).. But even when Facebook needed high availability systems (i.e. chat), they turned to other technology (namely Erlang for this specific case).

Answer (score 2):

Performance only? In the first example, you are using Smarty, a fairly weighty library composed of thousands of lines of PHP code. In the next two, you are using three lines of PHP *only*. Of course those two will be much faster, with less overhead, since PHP doesn't have to parse Smarty first.

As for whether string concatenation or substation of variables, and which quotes etc. are faster, it's a micro-optimization not likely to make a difference at a sub-Facebook scale. One or the other is merely saving nanoseconds. You can read live comparisons on this page: http://www.phpbench.com/ if that helps.